# Is there a way to create a new instance for IRequestDictionary and IStringList on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, com, asp-classic, comobject

We are working on a C# DLL that stores the values of a Classic ASP Session.

Everything is okay *but* some QueryStrings being stored in Session. Problem is: we are able to read the QueryString from the DLL using IRequestDictionary and IStringList, but we can't find a way to recreate them the next time a page ask for them.

We have stored all information necessary to recreate them.

So, the question is: Is it possible to instantiate and set their values back? Is there any other option?

Comment: Can you eloborate on "some QueryString being stored in Session".  It doesn't make sense.  If a value from QueryString is stored in session then the value that gets stored is a string unless the code is doing something highly ill-advised like `Set` the querystring object into the session.

Comment: Not really, if you use 'Session("blah") = Request.QueryString("x")', the session does not store a String, but something that resembles an array (which I can access in C# as a "IStringList" interface). To store a real string we should use 'Request.QueryString("x")(0)'...

That was big surprise to me.

Comment: Also, it's possible to do 'Session("blah") = Request.QueryString', which appears on C# as "IRequestDictionary'. Oddly, after put that in session, this is perfectly legal in ASP: 'if Session("blah") = "" then ...' (I mean, comparing it to a string)